# Reduce code in a javascript for statement with a group of divs and inputs inside

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a form with conditional fields that appear based on the user's selection in another field. I am using a wordpress plugin so the fields came with their own class and I have to adapt my code to that.

I already found the solution, but I am wondering if there is a way to reduce my code for those conditional fields.

This is my code:

```js
// This nodelist get all divs that are conditionals, with their labels and inputs. 
var b = document.querySelectorAll('.um-is-conditional');
for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  b[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```js
// This nodelist get all inputs inside those divs that are conditional
var c = document.querySelectorAll('.um-is-conditional input');
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
  c[i].required = false;
}
```

Let me know if its possible to fusion both for statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `input` is a child of the `.um-is-conditional` element, you can query for the `input` while in the main (first) loop.

```js
// This nodelist get all divs that are conditionals, with their labels and inputs. 
var b = document.querySelectorAll('.um-is-conditional');
for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  b[i].style.display = "none";
  
  // THE input inside the div that IS conditional
  b[i].querySelector('input').required = false;
}
```

You can further simplify this to:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.um-is-conditional').forEach(el => {
  el.style.display = 'none';
  el.querySelector('input').required = false;
});
```

Comment: The simplified version worked perfectly. I have never used that method before.Thanks.

Comment: @NicolásChaccal You can use the "spread operator" (`...`) to spread the resulting node list from the query into an array so that you can iterate over the data easily.

Comment: querySelectorAll has forEach so the spread is not needed.

Comment: @epascarello sorry, I misspoke... But if you need to anything like filter/map/reduce the elements, you will need to spread. Thanks.